# Fetch data from Facebook graph api without loging in

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In the app I'm making I need to get some public information from a Facebook page. How can I do this without making the user login in their facebook account and accept my app? Is it possible?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an app token.  Get it from the access tokens tool.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

With the access token, create a session in the app with FBSession `openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(Context, AccessToken, StatusCallback)` method.

docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/

Comment: Where do I put that app token? Inside my app?

Comment: Added something.  You use the token to create a session with the SDK before making requests.

Comment: Thank you it worked, now I read it's dangerous to keep the app token in the source code, how can I circumvent this?

Comment: You could use a cloud code function to return it, but that still could be sniffed if someone is motivated enough.  Not sure we have a great answer for that, besides not doing your app-token based requests from a user device.  (moar cloud code!)